# Installation Error in bika lims

Tags: python, ubuntu-16.04, plone

I am new in BIKA LIMS, also new in Ubuntu environment. I am try to install bika lims following thats link [bika lims](https://github.com/bikalims/bika.lims/wiki/bika.lims-Installation) but after execute this command:

```
sudo -u plone_buildout bin/buildout
```

I got an error:

```
Updating zeoserver.
Installing client1.
/home/shamim/Downloads/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/setuptools-27.3.0-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py:188: RuntimeWarning: You have iterated over the result of pkg_resources.parse_version. This is a legacy behavior which is inconsistent with the new version class introduced in setuptools 8.0. In most cases, conversion to a tuple is unnecessary. For comparison of versions, sort the Version instances directly. If you have another use case requiring the tuple, please file a bug with the setuptools project describing that need.
  stacklevel=1,
Couldn't find index page for 'bika.lims' (maybe misspelled?)
Getting distribution for 'bika.lims'.
Couldn't find index page for 'bika.lims' (maybe misspelled?)
While:
  Installing client1.
  Getting distribution for 'bika.lims'.
Error: Couldn't find a distribution for 'bika.lims'.
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1):

just add the line 'index=https://pypi.python.org/simple/' (without the single quotes) in the [buildout] section of the buildout.cfg file and it should work